# I have a list of users id , i want to check every userid available or not, if not i want to get the follwing id which is not available

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-rest-framework

Here is the code that i have tryed

```
staffids = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
# up_obj = UserProfile.objects.filter(userId__in = staffids) #i will explain it below 
flag=0
unknown = []
for x in staffids:
    up_obj = UserProfile.objects.filter(userId=x)
    if up_obj.exists():
       print(up_obj)
    else:
       flag=1
       unknown.append({
          "id": x
       })
 if flag == 1:
    return Response({
       STATUS:False,
       MESSAGE:"User not found",
       DATA:unknown
    })
```

This code returns only the available users

```
up_obj = UserProfile.objects.filter(userId__in = staffids)
```

suppose if the userid 3,4 not available , this code return the queryset with out 3,4.

If all id are not present i want to return a  message that the following ids are not available or somethis else..., i have tryed but im looking for a better way for doing this

Is there any buildin method in django?

Comment: Can you be a bit more concise as to what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: ok, suppose i have a list of userid say 1,2,3,4,5 . what i want is if all the id are available in the table or not, if some id are not in the table i want to get those ids back with that i have to do more stuffs

Comment: @Jasir see my answer below, there you get exactly what you described.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making a query for every entry in `staffids` you can do a single query for getting all `userId`-fields available through `UserProfile`:

```
all_user_ids = list(UserProfile.objects.all().values_list('userId', flat=True))
```

Then you can easily find the difference between the two lists, giving you the information which ids are missing.

With that you can print out which exactly are missing or whatever you want to do with that information.

```
staffids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
qs = UserProfile.objects.all()
all_user_ids = list(qs.values_list('userId', flat=True))

if not all_user_ids:
    # do something ...
else:
    missing_ids = list(set(staffids) - set(all_user_ids))
    # do something ...

    for obj in qs:
        print(obj)
```

Comment: Actually i have done like this, but in my case iteration is needed to get the further details.

Comment: @Jasir I edited the answer. The only thing I can see where you need the existing models is in `print(up_obj)`. You can do this here as well.

Comment: @Jasir was your problem solved with this? If so, please [consider marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).